# Retrieve status of triggered pipeline using an API in Tekton

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, cicd, tekton, tekton-pipelines

When we perform Tekton trigger API using an eventlistener, I am getting following response while in the background, pipeline runs for certain period of time.

Is there any API to fetch the status of this pipelineRun using the given `eventID` or `eventListenerUID`?

```
{
  "eventListener": "listener",
  "namespace": "default",
  "eventListenerUID": "ea71a6e4-9531-43a1-94fe-6136515d938c",
  "eventID": "14a657c3-6816-45bf-b214-4afdaefc4ebd"
}
```

Ref - https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/main/docs/eventlisteners.md#labels-in-eventListeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that eventID resolving your pipelinerun:

```
kubectl -n <your-namespace> get pr -l triggers.tekton.dev/tekton-eventid=<your-event-id>
```

Then, extract the status column, or use jsonpath to access `status.conditions[0].type`.

Comment: Yeah got it, but i wanted an api but unfortunately kubectl presence is not applied to my environment so that i could call via python subprocess. But anyways, i found an alternative directly via tekton api.